# qtcreator 3.5.1 (Qt 5.5.1) crashes on Ubuntu 14.04, VritualBox Could not initialize GLX Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: 14.04, qt, opengl, qt-creator

I just installed Qt 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS under VirtualBox 5.0.14.
I can't runt Qt Creator, after  a long list of warnings at the end it prints

> Could not initialize GLX Aborted (core dumped)

This is the complete output

```
libGL error: pci id for fd 21: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0ab24b48, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0ab24b48, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0ab24b48, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0ab24b48, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0ab24b48, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0ab24b48, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0ab24b48, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0ab24b48, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0ab24b48
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
Could not initialize GLX
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
ubuntu 14.04LTS under virtualbox 5.0.4

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654638/qt-creator-doesnt-launch-in-linux-mint-for-qt-5-5-1
Desativating 3D acceleration for display in VirtualBox worked for me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, more like a workaround.
I had to install the repository version of QtCreator, besides disabling 3D acceleration.

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```